# change laravel resource url

Tags: laravel, security, url, laravel-5

is there a way to customize Laravel 5 resource URLs ?

For example, change `user/1/edit` to `user/edit`.

That's because I don't want anybody to see the id in the URL. I think it is database information and shouldn't be revealed.

**The point is** that I want to do this without changing my routes. On the other hands I want to do this by using resource routes I have and not by adding some new routes to them , as you know when you define a resource route in your project it automatically adds some predefined routes to the route table and you are forced to use them in the way they are. For example you have to send a GET request to user/{user} for showing the user. Now I want to have a URL like user/{username} for doing this without adding a new route, IS THAT EVEN POSSIBLE?

if there is a way for achieving this I appreciate it if you share it here.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Since in most cases `id` is an auto incremented value and guessable, better you can use any other unique column of `users` table here, e.g username and then using that column instead of `id` in resource controller. Suppose you've an unique `username` column in your table So, if you use that instead of id your call to user edit will be like:

```
{!! route('user.edit', $user->username) !!} // let's say username is shahrokhi
```

which is equivalent to

```
user/shahrokhi/edit
```

Now for example, in your resource controller to edit a user details code may be like:

```
public function edit($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->firstOrFail();
    // rest of your code goes here

}
```

And so on for other methods.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do this? `Using another unique column instead of id`

Comment: Thanks a lot , but I just realized I had forgot to mention one important point in my problem . I edited my post and now it says completely what I want to achieve. It would be really nice of you if take a look at it again!

Comment: I checked. Your resource routes will be same as before. Nothing to change on your routes. You just need to use `username` instead of `id` in controller methods. That's all.

Comment: Are you sure? because I have put `{!! route('user.edit', $user->username) !!}` in my blade and the only deference is that instead of `username` my unique column is `mobileNumber`. but when I type `user/[some mobile number]/edit` I get the `Not Found` page.

Comment: Edit your question. Share your controller code also. Let's have a look at that.

Comment: Actually it does not get to execute controller code , because it returns `Not Found` page . Sounds like the problem occurs in my route file and it doesn't have anything special about user but the line `Route::resource('user', 'UserController');` and in my blade there is `{!! route('user.edit', $user->username) !!}`

Comment: Unless you update your question with your route, controller and views code snippet for related to your error I can't help you anymore. Please follow the SO guideline while you are looking for answers to your problem. Thanks.